# Method vs. function in case of simple function

Tags: python, oop

I have original class (DownloadPage) and I need to add just one *simple* functionality (get_info). What is better approach in OOP?

```
def get_info(page):  # make simple function
    ...
result = get_info(DownloadPage())
```

or

```
class MyDownloadPage(DownloadPage):   # make new class with inheritance
    def get_info(self):               # with one method
        ...

result = MyDownloadPage().get_info()
```

Thanks

Comment: Why aren't you subclassing and extending the subclass?  Why would a separate function even be a choice?  Is there some other consideration?  This doesn't seem to be a sensible design question unless there's some additional feature or aspect of the function that makes you think it shouldn't be a method.

Comment: Because it can be function as well as method. Two versions with same functionality. So I couldn't decide between them.

Comment: @Vojtech R.: Everything can be a function (hence functional programming).  That's not my question.  My question is *in this specific case* why did you think a function instead  of a method? A method is the standard, universal answer in OO programming.  The function choice is almost never used in OO design.  Why did you think it was relevant *in this specific case*?

Comment: @S.Lott: "A method is the standard, universal answer in OO programming." It's something I didn't know. Therefore the question. "Why did you think it was relevant in this specific case?" - just because it was possible...

Comment: @Vojtech R.: I ask because sometimes folks omit essential requirements that would indicate that a function made sense here.  Just because it's technically possible doesn't indicate that it's **meaningful**.  I needed to be sure there wasn't some hidden requirement that made the function more **meaningful** than a method.

Comment: @S.Lott: I humbly disagree with your unqualified statement that method is do-all-be-all solution in OO programming.

Comment: @Lie Ryan.  The alternative to object methods would be something that's not really OO programming.  It would be a hybrid of procedural (or functional) and OO programming.  Nothing wrong with that, but it isn't -- narrowly speaking -- OO programming.

Comment: @S.Lott: The primary tenet of OO programming is that you **send a message to an object to do its own things**. Calling the object's method is only one way of **telling the object what to do**. Other message passing mechanism exists, for example: a sender object writes a "message" to a shared file, and the receiver object reads this "message" at their leisure. They are still OOP even though there is no method calling involved. Similarly, OOP is not about method-calling, encapsulation, polymorphism, inheritence, etc; they are **techniques** used to achieve OOP, but not OOP itself.

Comment: @Lie Ryan: "They are still OOP even though there is no method calling involved".  That makes all programming OO, which then makes the term useless.  While OO analysis and OO design are perhaps universal.  OO programming -- I think -- should be restricted to OO languages.

Comment: @S.Lott: OO languages are languages that design its syntax specifically for OO paradigm, but you can use OO paradigm in any language, and you can write non-OO code in an OO language. And I disagree with your conclusion that that all programming is OO; functional programming is a counter-example. Being OO or functional is about the way you solve a problem, not about certain specific features of the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer truly depends on whether or not you want that `get_info` function/method can function on things other than a `MyDownloadPage`.  At present, I'd go with the free function but when requirements solidify one way or the other it should be easy enough to transform your solution either way.

(I prefer the free function because it doesn't restrict what can be passed to it, and any functionality that relies only on another object's public interface should be a function to reduce coupling.)

Comment: "get_info function/method can function on things other than a MyDownloadPage". It can't. So subclassing should be better choice.

Comment: Not necessarily- if all of that information is needed by the get_info function is available via the `MyDownloadPage` public interface, there's no need to make it a member function.

Answer (score 2):

Since the distance from one solution to the other is small, it hardly makes a difference with one function.

As soon as you have two functions, I'd say the derived class is more maintainable.

Once the two functions want to share a common value, like a logger or configuration variable, then you'll see more benefit.

Answer (score 1):

This may be heretical, by why not just add it as a method to the existing class?

```
def get_info(self):
    ...

DownloadPage.get_info = get_info
```

I realize this isn't exactly standard practice, but I'd be curious to hear Python experts explain why not.

Comment: Looks like we got a Ruby user here!

Comment: I think it may be confusing for somebody because "this isnt't exactly standard practice". I tend to use standard practices.